# Determining mean based on True/False in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got sample dataframe as below. And now trying to find % of Low income group in each country.

[image]

Output:

[image]

One solution would be :

```
(DF.Country[DF["Income"] == "Low"].value_counts() * 100 / DF.Country.value_counts())
```

Another is: Add third column in DF with True/False value against each record if Income='Low'. and then calculate mean.

Is there any better approach to achieve this?

Comment: Solution in R would be - tapply(DF$Income == "Low", DF$Country, mean)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` with normalize=True to get to your answer.

```
df['Income'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

If you want to break this down by Country, then you have to add that to the counts.

```
print (df[['Country','Income']].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100)
```

This will give me:

```
Country  Income 
M3       Low        28.571429
M2       VeryLow    14.285714
         Medium     14.285714
         High       14.285714
M1       Low        14.285714
         High       14.285714
```

Since you are looking for Mean of Income by each country, you have to group by Country.

```
print (df.groupby('Country')['Income'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100)
```

This will give you:

```
Country  Income 
M1       High        50.000000
         Low         50.000000
M2       High        33.333333
         Medium      33.333333
         VeryLow     33.333333
M3       Low        100.000000
```

Comment: Your answer would be true if i need to count mean for all records disregarding Country column. But here mean is required based on group by Country.

Comment: Does the additional info help?

Comment: Question: Do you want to know the mean compared to all the countries or mean compared to each country? For ex: `Low` for `M3`. It has two records in total. All of them are `Low`. So should `M3` represent `100.00` or `2/7` = `28.57 %`

Comment: Thanks. But it won't help as value_count running over whole data frame. Somehow this needs to have group by "Income". As mentioned on my question, M3 should have 100%.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to find the % of Income for each country. Let me tweak the answer a bit to give you that.

Comment: Still one step left as i need only records having Income="Low".

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
res = df.groupby("Country")["Income"].value_counts(normalize=True)

res = res.loc[res.index.get_level_values("Income") == "Low"].reset_index(level="Income", drop=True).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str) + " %"
```

Comment: Is there more pythonic way by chaining/Boolean indexing or something similar? R code solution for my problem would be tapply(DF$Income == "Low", DF$Country, mean) which looks more elegant.

Comment: I think that's pretty pythonic - filtering of low income however bad looking I think is the fastest to do that way...

Comment: Elegant, not efficient - `.apply` generally is the slowest solution - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186